# How to start, stop a server automatically, based on http requests?

Tags: linux, networking, proxy, http, scheduled-task

I am using cloud services (say AWS EC2) for my development servers. Those are generally big servers and I am paying for them. After I use them, sometimes I forgot them running for days so I end-up paying more.

**How can I start my instance when a http request is made on its http endpoint? "then" How can I stop my instance if there is no request received in last 1 hour?**

Please feel free to share any application, service, code or design.

Many Thanks

*Some more details to explain problem better:*

- When I try to reach a dev environment url, I am expecting to have a
  temporary web page (or proxy?) which says "starting server" then
  redirecting me to application afterwards.
- I am aware of scheduling in EC2. But I need automatic shutdown if no
  more request coming to that server. And I may try to access my server
  at any moment.
- I cant consider setting a cron job for shutting down. I need better
  solution, same cause with option above.

Comment: The HTTP requests are coming from you own development machine?

Comment: Most of the time yes, but not limited to it, maybe mobile app, or another server

Answer (score 3):

Basically two issues:

- one of starting up the VPS
- one for shutting it down

**Starting up**

First you would need to install the `ec2 cli tools`, https://aws.amazon.com/cli/

For starting you could create your own sever as a proxy (localhost). Create a php, python, etc. page that you can call. That pages ties to open a test page, if it timeout (x seconds) you call the cli ec2 for starting the specific instance.

Alternatively, you can call a ec2 script for starting up your VPS once your development server starts (i.e i'm doing Ruby on Rails, and it would be very easy to just call a script that would start the server, once i started my development code)

https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/ec2-example-managing-instances.html

**Shutting down**

For shutting down I would create a cron running on each of your development server, every x minutes (hourly?). There you basically tail the result of the development log and create a `MD5`, as long as the MD5 changes you know the server is beeing used. So for it to work i would take a good amount of time checking (i.e. not every minute). Added a email so you get notified when the shutdown is initiated.

**Assuming** your development log has a timestamp you should be good.

Example shutdown script script

```
#!/bin/sh
# /etc/cron.hour/autoshutdown
# Example EC2 auto shutdown script
# Place in your /etc/cron.hourly

LOG_FILE=/path/to/my/development.log
MD5_FILE=/tmp/my.log.md5
NOTIFY=me@somedomain.com

echo "Create MD5..."
cur_md5=`tail $LOG_FILE | md5`

echo "Read latest MD5..."
if [ -f $MD5_FILE ]; then
    last_md5=`cat $MD5_FILE`
else
    echo "No MD5 found, 1st time use..."    
    last_md5='no sig. found'
fi

if [ "$cur_md5" = "$last_md5" ]; then   
    echo "MD5 signatures are identical, nothing changed we can stop the server..."
    echo "Server is been shutdown" | mail -s "Server $(hostname) has been shutdown..." $NOTIFY
    # shutdown -h now
else
    echo "Current MD5 [$cur_md5]"
    echo "Last MD5   [$last_md5]"
    echo "MD5 changed, we are still using the sever..."
    echo "Updating signature..."
    echo $cur_md5 > $MD5_FILE
fi
```

Of course, **no guarantees**, just my thoughts ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Roger, especially for md5 checking of logs. I am willing to create a special purpose proxy for this one you mentioned. For shutting down I am looking for less invasive solution on target dev server.(May be impossible). So that one can install a proxy into his development machine, and provide real dev server credentials to this proxy, than proxy should manage rest.

Comment: @ozkolonur yeah I understand its invasive :( If you want to control it all via a proxy, I would implement some form of heartbeat, which is send from each of your dev servers to the proxy. Once the proxy misses -lets say 3 beats- it will shutdown the server. For the MD5, you can of-course use any log that would indicate wetter the server is being used (mysql, apache, nginx, etc.)